# Android: Incorrect touch resolution

Tags: android, touch, resolution, mismatch

I have a Teclast X80h and I flashed the Android 5.0 v7 mirek's ROM to it. It's original stock ROM was 4.4 Jellybean.
With the new firmware the display resolution and the touchscreen resolution is not the same.
If I move my finger on the screen then the contact indicator moving only on a pretty smaller area, maybe 20% of the display size.
[Touchscreen resolution mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMmhb.png)
See the attached picture. (If I touch at the big dots, it reacts at the small dots inside the yellow marked area.)
It is almost useless. At the moment I navigate with a mouse on the OTG.

What I tried:

- **Download a calibration software.**
  Failed it. I can not found any. Only sensitiveness calibrators exists for Android. On Windows You can calibrate coordinates, but on Android... Somewhere I read that the calibration data is hardcoded in the kernel.
- **Compare the stock ROM with the newly installed one, search for differences on drivers or config files.** The .idc files are the same in /system/usr/idc, and the .drvb files are the same in /system/vendor/firmware.
- **Modify the .idc file in /system/usr/idc** I found some content at Android's site about the Input Device Configuration files.
  I tried the following parameters:

  touch.scale (but it is corresponds to contact area size)

  raw.x.max (the maximum of the raw value received from the touchscreen)

  output.width (the displqy coordinate to associate to the max raw value)

  Anyway I tried almost all touch.* raw*. and output.*

Nothing helps.
BTW the uploaded firmware was created for another but very similar model X98 Air.
This firmware must work on this model as shown in a Youtube video "X80h Android 5".

Note: I have the skills to extract a ROM or decompile an .apk!

Should I replace a driver? Or is there a handy software?

Should I modify another config file? Or the kernel?

Thanks guys

Comment: this is not the rightplace to ask this question. You should ask it where you've downloaded the rom, or directly to a ROM author